# Exclude path from Windows 7 search?

Tags: windows-7, search

It's really quite incredible how bad Windows 7's search seems to be.  The latest problem I have with it is that I want to search for filenames including the string "user", so I go to the directory I want to search in (`C:\Users\jez\testing`), type `*user*` in the search box, and hit enter.  It gives me... every single file.  Because "user" is in the path of every file, with everything being under "C:\Users..."

OK, this is useless.  Is there a way to just search for the string within *files* rather than their *paths*, or do I need to download some decent 3rd party search software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search only filenames, prepend `name:` to your search. For example, your search would become

`name: *user*`.

[More on Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/bb233500.aspx) operators that you can use in Windows 7 Search

Comment: I just went to *C:\Users\<User Name>\Downloads* (which contains ~1000 files right now, but none with the string "user" in their name), typed `*user*` in the search field and it returned 0 results (just * of course displayed all files/folders). I'm not sure what's up with your system (I'm using Win7 Ultimate x64), but on mine it seems to be searching the actual names by default instead of the entire path.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Mine searches the path. I've only got Home Premium installed right now. I should probably figure out what I did with my Ultimate.

Comment: Maybe there's a setting for this hidden somewhere? Will have to look into it further... (Note that the folder I'm searching is *not* indexed.)